# How can I remove the video from Youtube using Codeigniter and library by Jim Saunders?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, youtube-api

I use Codeigniter and work with youtube API through the library by Jim Saunders.
https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-YouTube-API-Library

Upload the video, I was good but how to remove it without using Zend library?

I hope for your help :))

Comment: Ask Jim:::::::::::::::-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no method, you'll have to do it manually.

The docs show an example request for removing a video:

```
DELETE /feeds/api/users/default/uploads/VIDEO_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

With a quick glimpse to the source, here's how a request is made (inside the class):

```
$header = "DETELE /feeds/api/users/default/uploads/".$VIDEO_ID." HTTP/".self::HTTP_1.self::LINE_END;
$extra = "Content-Type: application/atom+xml".self::LINE_END;
$extra .= "GData-Version: 2".self::LINE_END;
$fullrequest = $this->_build_header(false, $header, $extra, 'POST');

$handle = $this->_connect();
$this->_write($handle, $fullrequest);
$output = $this->_read($handle);
fclose($handle);
$handle = null;
```

May not work completely, but hopefully pushes to the right direction.